# Find all distinct non negative integers numbers $x,y,w,z,t$ that $x+y+z+t+w=16$.

Tags: combinatorics

Find all distinct non-negative integers numbers $x,y,w,z,t$ that $x+y+z+t+w=16$.

If they weren't distinct the answer would be $\binom{15}{4}$.For calculating distinct cases I calculate the cases where two are equal then reduce from the main number then calculate cases where three are equal and so on.But it takes a long time.Isn't there an easier solution?

Comment: The number $\binom{15}{4}$ is the number of solutions of the equation $x+ y + z + t + w = 16$ in the positive integers, including those cases in which the numbers are not distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{x,y,w,z,t\}=\{0,1,2,3,10\}$, 
$\{0,1,2,4,9\}$, 
$\{0,1,2,5,8\}$, 
$\{0,1,2,6,7\}$, 
$\{0,1,3,4,8\}$, 
$\{0,1,3,5,7\}$, 
$\{0,1,4,5,6\}$, 
$\{0,2,3,4,7\}$, 
$\{0,2,3,5,6\}$ or
$\{1,2,3,4,6\}$.

There are totally $10\times 5!=1200$ solutions.

(If $x,y,w,z,t$ are not necessarily distinct, the number of solutions should be $C_4^{20}$.)

Note: If $x,y,w,z,t$ are distinct positive integers, then $\{x,y,w,z,t\}=\{1,2,3,4,6\}$. There are totally $5!=120$ solutions.